# Check the socket connection state in android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask

I am using an asyncTask which runs for every 1 sec.
I must check a condition every 1 sec that the socket connection is available or not before  asyncTask starts.

I used socket.isConnected() -> it always returning true.

How to do this.

Please help..

Comment: ' used socket.isConnected() -> it always returning true' - then you end of the virtual TCP connection is in the connected state. I suspect that this is not what you want - you want to know if the remote peer is reachable.  The only way to find that out is by trying to communicate with it.

Comment: 'I must check a condition every 1 sec that the socket connection is available' - not really, no.  You must design you system so that is resilient to communication failures.  Even if you implemented an application-level poll, (the usual way to detect unreachability 'early'), a 1-second timeout would fail on some links that are still viable - satellite and wireless links are notoriously laggy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, You must design you system so that is resilient to communication failures. how I know when socket connection is gone.?

Comment: You will know when a send or receive fails. As above, you can make this happen quicker if you can implement some app-level polling of the peer if there is nothing else to send/recv.

Comment: As with everything else in computing, and indeed in life, you can't tell in advance whether something will work. You have to try it, and cope with the failure when and if it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Once a connection is made, isConnected() will always return true.

To check if the connection is still alive, you can:

1. Use `socket.getInputStream().read()`. This will block until either some data arrives or the connection closes in which case it will return `-1`. Otherwise it will return the received byte. If you use `socket.setSoTimeout(t)` and then call `read()`, 3 things can happen:

   a) The connection closes and `read()` returns `-1`;

   b) Some data arrives and `read()` returns the read byte.

   c) `read()` will block for `t` miliseconds and throw `SocketTimeoutException` which means no data was received and the connection is okay.

- If you want to ckeck the connection quickly, set the timeout to 1. If you set it to 0, it will block indefinitely which is the default.

<s>2. Use `socket.getInetAddress().isReachable(int timeout)`.</s>

Comment: `socket.getInetAddress().isReachable(int timeout)` does not test the connection. It tests the reachablility of the IP address via *another* connection.

Answer (score -1):

Its too late but it may help someone else all you need to do is just check for your socket if it is not null and then in case if it is not null just disconnect your socket else create new socket and connect that

```
    if(socket != null) {
        socket.disconnect();
    } else {
        socket.createSocket();
        socket.connect();
    }
```

here create socket is method in which you can create your socket
Hope it may help someone.

Comment: There is no such method as `Socket.disconnect()`, or `Socket.createSocket()` either, and even if there were they wouldn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CheckSocket extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.15.101", 23);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(socket.isConnected()){
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: connected");
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: not connected");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Comment: If the exception was thrown this will cause an NPE at `socket.isConnected()`, which in any case doesn't tell you anything except that the initial `connect()` succeeded. And the question is about an existing connection, not a new one. And you're leaking sockets.